# How to convert Postgres types to Rust native types

Tags: postgresql, rust

This is my SQL structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

When I run the following code:

```rust
struct Password {
   id: u32,
   title: String,
   username: String,
   password: String,
}
let items = self.client.query("SELECT * FROM passwords", &[]).unwrap().iter().map(|row| {
            let password = Password::new_with_id(
                row.get("id"),
                row.get("title"),
                row.get("username"),
                row.get("password"),
            );
            password
        }).collect();
```

I get these errors:

```
thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\k\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-postgres-0.7.10\src\row.rs:151:25:
error retrieving column id: error deserializing column 0: cannot convert between the Rust type `u32` and the Postgres type `int4`
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\PaTUI.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

How do I successfully convert between the Postgres type `int4` and the Rust type `u32`?

Comment: This page might help: https://kotiri.com/2018/01/31/postgresql-diesel-rust-types.html

Comment: yes, this was helpful. thank you!

Comment: Nice. :-) If you find the right int-type in Rust you can write an answer as well with the proper type. Good luck.

Comment: `int4` sounds like a 32-bits signed integer → `i32` in Rust.

Comment: Offtopic: passwords should be hashed and not extracted from a database.

Comment: @FrankHeikens not off-topic at all. Hey Khacke, um, ...https://plaintextoffenders.com/about/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tokio_postgres` uses `postgres_types` under the hood [which defines `int4` as an `i32`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/c5ff8cfd86e897b7c197f52684a37a4f17cecb75/postgres-types/src/lib.rs#L727).